# Instance Variable Declaration Syntax

Tags: java, class, object, constructor, instance-variables

I'm seeing what appears to my novice eyes as conflicting conventions in Java, when it comes to declaring instance variables. For example, a classic bank account instance variable might look like this, which makes perfect sense.

```
private double balance = 0.0;
```

An access modifier, data type, variable name, and a value are all I (mistakenly) thought went into an instance variable.  Now the confusing part.

Consider a library/class/package that is imported, named ColorImage.  It apparently has a canvas object, but here's what the instance variable declarations look like.

```
private Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
private ColorImage image1 = new ColorImage("file.gif");
```

Now it looks like object names, and even the name of the library/package/class itself, are being used as data types.  Moreover, the instance variables have been joined to what look like constructors.

My question:
Why is this second syntax ok when it looks like it deviates wildly from the first?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem? You don't know the difference between primitives and objects?

Answer (score 5):

> Why is this second syntax ok when it looks like it deviates wildly from the first?

It doesn't deviate *at all* from the first.

```
Part                        First example       Second example
Access modifier             private             private
Type                        double              Canvas
Name                        balance             canvas
Initialization expression   0.0                 new Canvas()
```

Where do you see the discrepancy? Yes, the type can be a class, not just a primitive. Yes, the initialization expression can be any expression (that doesn't use other instance variables) not just a literal. That doesn't change the *syntax* at all.

Note that the access modifier is optional (defaulting to "package access"), and there are other potential modifiers (`volatile`, `final`, `static`). But in your examples, the set of modifiers applied is exactly the same.

Comment: Appreciate the response. No, I did not know I could use classes as data types, instead of primitives.

Comment: @NewGuy_IL: If you couldn't use classes as data types for variables, they wouldn't be very much use...

Answer (score 3):

> An access modifier, data type, variable name, and a value are all I (mistakenly) thought went into an instance variable

It's actually the same:

```
private ColorImage image1 = new ColorImage("file.gif");
```

> **private** - access modifier 
>   **ColorImage** - data type 
>   **image1** - variable name 
>   **new ColorImage("file.gif")** - expression that creates a new object and returns the value of the object reference

Java data types can be *primitive types* or *reference types*. In your example, `double` is a primitive type, and `ColorImage` and `Canvas` are both reference types.

To the right side of the `=` you could have any expression:

```
private double balance = 1.0 - 1.0;
```

or

```
private double balance = zero();
static double zero() {
    return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this very lucid explanation.  This helped a lot.